# If element is empty hide next element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to find a way to hide a preceding `<td>`'s contents if the one above it is empty. I have my table set up as such:

```
<tr>
  <td class="firsttd">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="nexttd">
  Hide me if above TD is empty
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="firsttd">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="nexttd">
  Hide me if above TD is empty
  </td>
</tr>
```

And so far have:

```
$(".firsttd").each(function( index ) {
    var dotlenght = $(this).html().length;

    if (dotlenght < 1){
        $(this).next('.nexttd').hide();
    } 
});
```

But cannot get it to work correctly. I cannot figure our how to tell JQuery which element to target.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try to trim your html content using `$.trim()`

Comment: you could use `$( "td:empty" )` for selecting empty td.

Comment: @hitman: not if it contains white-space s/he can't; unless jQuery implements a non-standard version of CSS `:empty` pseudo-class.

Comment: @DavidThomas sorry!.. I did'nt know that.Thanks for the info.

Comment: _"If element is empty hide next element"_ , _"I want to be able to find a way to hide a preceding <td>'s contents if the one above it is empty"_ Is requirement to hide a) _next_ element ? or b) _"preceding"_ element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
 $(this).parent().next().find('.nexttd').hide();
            ||     ||     ^^------find td `.nexttd`
            ||     ^^------Traverse to next tr
            ^^------Traverse to parent tr
```

Also you do not need to iterate over elements individually. You can target all first td elements that are empty using `.filter()` function and can narrow down the complete code to:

```
  $( "td.firsttd" ).filter(function(){
      return $(this).html() == "";
  }).parent().next().find('.nexttd').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code.

First is the length of the content:

```
$(this).html().length; // will produce 1

$.trim($(this).html()).length; // will produce 0
```

The second one is hiding the next row:

```
 $(this).next().find('.nexttd').hide();
```

should be:

```
 $(this).parent().next().find('.nexttd').hide();
```